# Codeigniter post variable with empty value

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have nine text boxes wrapped in a form but when post to codeigniter controller, there are two specific text boxes have no value but they actually have.
Anyone encountered this issue before ? what is actually wrong ?

Form

```
<form name="frm_RRequest" id="frm_RRequest" action="<?php echo site_url('user/add_recommendation_request/'); ?>" method="post">                   
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="col-left">Date</td>
                    <td class="col-middle"><input class="datepicker" type="text" name="txtStartDate" id="txtStartDate" class="datepicker" placeholder="Click to select a start date.."></td>
                    <td class="col-middle"><input class="datepicker" type="text" name="txtEndDate" id="txtEndDate" class="datepicker" placeholder="Click to select a end date.."></td>
                    <td class="col-right"><div class="error" id="error_date">&nbsp;</div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="col-left">Travel time</td>
                    <td class="col-middle"><input type="text" class="ptTimeSelect input" name="txtStartTime" id="txtStartTime" placeholder="Click to select start time.." data-default-time="false"></td>
                    <td class="col-middle"><input type="text" class="ptTimeSelect input" name="txtEndTime" id="txtEndTime" placeholder="Click to select end time.." data-default-time="false"></td>
                    <td class="col-right"><div class="error" id="error_time">&nbsp;</div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="col-left">Location</td>
                    <td class="col-middle-2"><input type="text" class="inputWithImge" name="txtStartLocation" id="txtStartLocation" onmouseover="display_text(this)" placeholder="Click the icon to select a start point"/><img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/search_icon.png'); ?>" class="location-icon" title="Click to show map" name="location-icon_start" value="StartLocation"/></td>
                    <td class="col-middle-2"><input type="text" class="inputWithImge" name="txtEndLocation" id="txtEndLocation" onmouseover="display_text(this)" placeholder="Click the icon to select a end point"/><img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/search_icon.png'); ?>" class="location-icon" title="Click to show map" name="location-icon_end" value="EndLocation" /></td>
                    <td class="col-right"><div class="error" id="error_location">&nbsp;</div></td>
                  </tr>
                <input type="hidden" name="txtStartLocation_Coordinates" id="txtStartLocation_Coordinates">
                <input type="hidden" name="txtEndLocation_Coordinates" id="txtEndLocation_Coordinates">
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>

            <div><input type="button" class="button" id="btnGo" name="btnGo" value="Input detail" />&nbsp; <span> << click this button if the travel time and location(s) are different for each day</span></div>
            <div id="detail"> 

            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="txtTotalDetail" id="txtTotalDetail">
            <input type="hidden" name="txtNoOfDays" id="txtNoOfDays">
            <div>&nbsp;</div>
            <div><input type="button" id="btn_SaveDetail" name="btn_SaveDetail" class="button" value="Save" /></div>
            </form>

<script>
    function display_text(obj){
        var value = obj.value;
        obj.title = value;

    }
</script>
```

Controller :

```
$total_detail = $this->input->post("txtTotalDetail");
        $noOfDays = $this->input->post("txtNoOfDays");
        $userid = $this->session->userdata('id');

        $start_date = $this->input->post("txtStartDate");
        $end_date = $this->input->post("txtEndDate");
        $start_time = $this->input->post("txtStartTime");
        $end_time = $this->input->post("txtEndTime");
        $start_location = $this->input->post("txtStartLocation");
        $end_location = $this->input->post("txtEndLocation");
        $start_location_coor = $this->input->post("txtStartLocation_Coordinates");
        $end_location_coor = $this->input->post("txtEndLocation_Coordinates");
```

These two text boxes have no value :

```
$start_location = $this->input->post("txtStartLocation");
    $end_location = $this->input->post("txtEndLocation");
```

Comment: Which  two specific text boxes have no value??

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: show your display_text(this) jquery code...

Comment: it's only showing the value of the text box as the title

Comment: Array
(
    [txtStartDate] => dgfdf
    [txtEndDate] => dgfgdf
    [txtStartTime] => dfgdf
    [txtEndTime] => dfgdf
    [txtStartLocation] => dfgdfgdfg
    [txtEndLocation] => ghjghj
    [txtStartLocation_Coordinates] => 
    [txtEndLocation_Coordinates] => 
    [txtTotalDetail] => 
    [txtNoOfDays] => 
    [btn_SaveDetail] => Save
)
i got this array when hit to controller

Comment: those two variables have value in your array. But when I echo mine, they are empty

Comment: can you show `display_text(this)` function ?

Comment: i have added it to my question

Comment: can u plz explain what  r u trying to do with display_text(this)..??

Comment: it's only showing the value of the text box as the title. The value can be longer that the text box size

Comment: I have tried to remove this function and it does not change anything. the value of the text boxes are still displayed as empty in controller

Comment: Can you try by giving different name for those two text boxes?

Comment: For debbugging, try `echo '<pre>'.print_r($_POST, true).'</pre>'` in your controller.

Comment: Can you show `$this->form_validation->set_rules()` section?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you forgot to use `$this->form_validation->set_rules()` on those particular fields.

Answer (score 0):

Put value in your input tag like

```
<input type="hidden" name="txtStartLocation_Coordinates" value ="<?php echo $this->input->post('txtStartLocation_Coordinates');?>" id="txtStartLocation_Coordinates">
<input type="hidden" name="txtEndLocation_Coordinates" value ="<?php echo $this->input->post('txtEndLocation_Coordinates');?>" id="txtEndLocation_Coordinates">
<script>
    $(function(){
      $('#txtStartLocation_Coordinates').val("your value");
      $('#txtEndLocation_Coordinates').val("your value");
    });
 </script>
```